# Is there a natural topology on C(X), if X is infinite-dimensional?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Suppose $X$ is an infinite-dimensional Banach space.

Is there a natural topology on $$C(X)=\{f:X\to\mathbb{R}: \text{ $f$ is continuous}\}?$$

Comment: @NateEldredge Oops, I did not read the first line...

Comment: @NateEldredge, exactly. It is not clear what would be a family of seminorms that gives $C(X)$ a Frechet space topology.

Comment: @Cantor Sorry, my comment was absolutely pointless, I had not read the question carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few, one example would be the weak* topology:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology

Comment: So, what is one natural weak topology on $C(X)$?!

Comment: @Cantor: Sorry, meant to say the weak* topology.  It's the weak topology with respect to the functions $\{\phi\mapsto \phi(x) \ | \ x \in X\}$.

Comment: I think weak topology was correct.

Comment: Well, the weak* topology is a weak topology.  It's just that if you say weak topology that's a topology you put on a space using a set of functions on that space.  We have a space and a set of functions but we don't want a topology on $X$, we want a topology on $C(X)$, so it's a little confusing to just say weak topology.  If we want the topology to be on $C(X)$ we have to specify the functions on $C(X)$ that we are taking the weak topology with respect to.  By saying weak* topology I'm just being specific about what those functions are.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are saying to take the weak topology induced by the family of functionals: $Y'=\{\phi_x:C(X)\to R: \phi_x f=f(x)\}$ right?

Comment: Yes, that is the definition of the weak* topology.

Comment: I don't want to make this into a long discussion, but I still think the term weak topology is correct. We are putting a weak topology on C(X). Weak* topology is the weak topology that is put on the dual of a space, i.e. the space of continuous, 'linear' functionals on that space.